# i have to get which text has gift wrapped: yes in the string

Tags: php

if my  **$text**  is **"color: green, size: 10cm, gift wrapped: yes"** 
the string conses the words it failed to print "found"

```
 $text =$item_meta->display($flat=true,$return=true);
    $pos = strpos($text, 'gift wrapped: yes');
        if ($pos == false) {
            print "Not found\n";
        } else {
            print "Found!\n";
        }
```

this the piece of code i used to test but failed

can any one help me in this situation

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. What "failed"? How? And I'm pretty sure you're using default function arguments incorrectly. Perhaps you could work on your question-writing skill as all three pages of questions on your profile show the same pattern.

Comment: this could help you out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: I ran your code with the text "color: green, size: 10cm, gift wrapped: yes" and it returned Found!. So make sure $text is actually what you think it is - print it out to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

```
<?php
    $text ="color: green, size: 10cm, gift wrapped: yes";
    $pos = strpos($text, 'gift wrapped: yes');
    if ($pos === false) {
        print "Not found\n";
    } else {
        print "Found!\n";
    }
```

?>

Comment: Even when that's a valid consideration, how is it answering the question?